# Android Bug? Multiple animations don't animate at the same time

Tags: android, xml, animation

So I'm applying **one** animation to multiple ImageViews (arrows) and using the AnimationSet class to do so, see below:

```
Animation animInstruct;
//Inside onCreate
animInstruct = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_instructions);
ImageView arrow_bottomright = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.arrow2);
ImageView arrow_bottomleft = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.arrow3);
ImageView arrow_topleft = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.arrow0);
ImageView arrow_topright = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.arrow1);

AnimationSet start_atsame_time = new AnimationSet(true);
start_atsame_time.addAnimation(animInstruct);
arrow_topleft.setAnimation(start_atsame_time);
arrow_topright.setAnimation(start_atsame_time);
arrow_bottomleft.setAnimation(start_atsame_time);
arrow_bottomright.setAnimation(start_atsame_time);
start_atsame_time.start();
```

In my XML (anim_instructions):

```
<alpha      
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
    android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatCount="5"  />
</set>
```

However, when I run the application **(on an actual device)**, all arrows fade in/fade out at the same time but after the first iteration, one arrow takes longer to fade out while the others stay on track with each other. I don't know if its just the device's hardware limitations, an android bug, or something else?

Comment: Noticed this with view animations myself. Single animation just causes a lot of problems when used on multiple views. I end up using `clearAnimation()` a lot or simply create multiple instances of same animation, whichever is feasible. I'd love to hear a proper explanation of this.

Comment: So does the way you describe eliminate the problem? It sounds like a reasonable hack.

Comment: Loading the same animation in multiple anim instances does seems to solve the problem. But, I believe that might get slightly [unnecessarily] heavy in terms of resource usage. Use with caution.

Comment: Thanks will do this. Might try to post this in Android community blog post

Comment: By any chance, are you running the newest version of Android Studio 2.0? I don't know if the bug is fixed since I haven't downloaded the newest version.

Comment: Yeah and I've facing the issue since Studio was in dev preview. So, must not be associated with that.